# Easier way to replace a few words with abbreviations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that pulls addresses from a column like "1 Spooner Street", but I need to abbreviate "Street", "Apartment", etc.

I know I can wrap the column name in REPLACE a whole bunch of times for each case but I was wondering if there was a different way to do this.

Any ideas? Tips?

Comment: Look into regular expressions perhaps?

Comment: Do you have to do this in TSQL? It has very poor support for string manipulation (e.g. no regular expressions) and cleaning up address data is usually [difficult](http://www.diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/street_addresses.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion that might work would be to create a table with all of the values that you want to use to replace, similar to this:

```
create table replacements
(
    id int identity primary key,
    orig_value varchar(50) not null,
    new_value varchar(50) not null
);

insert into replacements values
('Street', 'St'),
('Drive', 'Dr'),
('Boulevard', 'Blvd'),
('Apartment', 'Apt');
```

Then you could join this table of replacements to your primary table and use `REPLACE()`.  Some sample data:

```
create table addresses
(
    id int identity primary key,
    addr1 varchar(100) not null
);

insert into addresses values
('123 Main Street'),
('235 Blah Boulevard'),
('78 E Test Drive'),
('78 E Multiple Lane Apartment 23');
```

Finally you can create a function that can be used to replace the values with those that exist in the table.  Function script:

```
create function replace_name
(
    @orig_value varchar(50)
)
returns varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @new_address varchar(50)
    declare @i int = 0
    declare @totalReplacements int


    set @totalReplacements = (select COUNT(*) 
                                from dbo.replacements r
                                where @orig_value like '%'+r.orig_value+'%')
    set @new_address = @orig_value


    if @totalReplacements > 0
        begin
            while @i < @totalReplacements
                begin
                    set @new_address = (select top 1 replace(@new_address, r.orig_value, r.new_value)
                                        from dbo.replacements r
                                        where @new_address like '%'+r.orig_value+'%')

                    if @i <= @totalReplacements
                        set @i = @i + 1
                end
        end
    else 
        begin 
            set @new_address = @orig_value;
        end


    return @new_address;
END
```

Then when you query the data, you will pass in the address to the function:

```
select a.id, 
  a.addr1, 
  dbo.replace_name(a.addr1) newAddress
from dbo.addresses a;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4db9c/3). This will give results:

```
| ID |                            ADDR1 |              NEWADDRESS |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |                  123 Main Street |             123 Main St |
|  2 |               235 Blah Boulevard |           235 Blah Blvd |
|  3 |                  78 E Test Drive |            78 E Test Dr |
|  4 | 57 E Multiple Drive Apartment 23 | 57 E Multiple Dr Apt 23 |
|  5 |                        19 E none |               19 E none |
```

Comment: upvoted and bookmarked. im not the OP but this may come in handy some day.

Comment: @bluefeet awesome man, thanks for walking through it too. definitely learned something!

Answer (score 0):

another idea (no code) is to create another table with two strings - one for a full word and one for the abbreviation.

then in your procedure, loop on those entries, search for the full word in the original record, and replace with the abbreviation.

in this way, the code will be shorter and easier to read - and the behavior will be data driven and not hardcoded when you need to add one more abbreviation to the list.