# SQL server RegEx query

Tags: sql-server, regex

I have a string in  `@SzQuickSearch` in a sql proc.
The string sometimes contains an address: **123 Smith St.**
If a user, or myself tries to search that string from **123 Smith Street**, I get nothing back.

So, I'm trying to figure out a way to deal with this. It also happens with `Ave. (Avenue)` and `Rd. (Road)`

The query now looks something like this

```
Or s.szAddress_StreetName like '%' + @szQuickValue + '%'
```

`szAdress_StreeName` would contain '123 Smith Street', and `@szQuickvalue` has the user entered value of '123 Smith St.'

How can I return the record for **123 Smith St**, when someone search for **123 Smith Street**?

Comment: See [Easier way to replace a few words with abbreviations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523305/easier-way-to-replace-a-few-words-with-abbreviations) and ideally normalize on write.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a "canonical" form of the word and do a search and replace of the synonyms which you store in a column side by side with the original.

When the user search you also do this search and replace, match the column containing the canonical form and give back the original.

SQL Server does not support regex (just a few wildcards) and the approach described above will offer the chance of good performance.

**Update 1**

```
Select col from table where colCanonical = 'The teacher'
```

Where SearchString is also processed so that all words are replaced with the canonical form. The user could have given 'The master ...'

Sample data

```
col             colCanonical 
The master ...   The teacher ... 
The teacher ...  The teacher ...
```

Comment: Sorry, just got back from vacation and saw this. Thanks for the reply. Can you give me an example of what you are saying " match the column containing the canonical form and give back the original." Are you saying to do this in SQL? If so, please post some short example code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks buckley. That helps a lot!